# Rails, Post & REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

So I have created a ruby script that tries to Post data to a DB via REST, here is the method.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://assignment-cloned-pas43.c9users.io")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

##Gets newest ID
newId = getBroadcastsLatestIdAndIncrementByOne
##Setting up our resource for REST
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/broadcasts", {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})
##JSON Data
request.body = {:id=>newId, :content=>"hello", :user_id=>41}.to_json
response = http.request(request)
puts "\n\nResponse Code: ", response.code, "\n"
#puts response.body
```

end

And below is the server response, But I get back a HTTP 204 error, when I check the DB nothing has been added and I'm confused why?

[image: Confused]

From looking at Broadcast I should only need  ID, Content & User and I have sent this data in a Post but as you can see I still get the 204.

```
class Api::BroadcastsController < Api::ApplicationController

  before_action :set_broadcast, only: [:show, :create, :new]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :squelch_record_not_found

  # This is an admin specific controller, so enforce access by admin only
  # This is a very simple form of authorisation
  ##before_action :admin_required #No admin for REST App

  # Default number of entries per page
  #PER_PAGE = 12

  # GET /broadcasts.json
  def index
      @broadcasts = Broadcast.paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: params[:per_page]).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /broadcasts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /broadcasts/new
  def new
    @broadcast = Broadcast.new
  end

  # POST /broadcasts.json
  def create
    @broadcast = Broadcast.new(broadcast_params)
    #puts "\n\n", broadcast_params, "\n\n"
    # Wire up broadcast with the current user (an administrator)
    # Will be an admin user (see before_action)
    # Note the current_user is a user_detail object so we need
    # to navigate to its user object
    @broadcast.user = User.find(41)

    # Doing the next line forces a save automatically. I want to defer this
    # until the "if" statement
    #current_user.user.broadcasts << @broadcast

    no_errors = false
    respond_to do |format|
      if @broadcast.save

        # Only after saving do we try and do the real broadcast. Could have been
        # done using an observer, but I wanted this to be more explicit
        results = BroadcastService.broadcast(@broadcast, params[:feeds])
        if results.length > 0
          # Something went wrong when trying to broadcast to one or more of the
          # feeds.
          @broadcast.errors[:base] << ("#{I18n.t('broadcasts.unable-message')}: #{results.inspect}")
          flash[:error] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-but-message')
        else
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-message')
          no_errors = true
        end
        if no_errors
          format.json { render json: @broadcast, status: :created, location: @broadcast }
        else
          format.json {
            # Either say it partly worked but send back the errors or else send
            # back complete failure indicator (couldn't even save)
            if results
              render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :created, location: @broadcast
            else
              render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end


  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_broadcast
    @broadcast = Broadcast.find(params[:id])
  end


  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def broadcast_params
    params.require(:broadcast).permit(:content)
  end

  def squelch_record_not_found(exception)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the Broadcast class.

```
class Broadcast < ApplicationRecord

  # The only restriction is that broadcasts must have some data to
  # be valid and an associated broadcaster (user_id)
  validates_presence_of :content

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :feeds

  def to_s
    result = "id: " + id.to_s + " content: " + content
    if user
      result += " user: " + user.id.to_s
    end
    result
  end

  def self.per_page
    8
  end
end
```

I'm new to rails and finding all the implicitness a hard task to grasp. Any help is much appreciated. If needed just goto https://c9.io/pas43/ and check out assignment-cloned.

Thanks.

Comment: 204 isn't an error. All 2xx codes are success, and 204 No Content is the appropriate response to a successful Ajax POST. Please post your controller `create` code in the question, and get rid of the images. Text is much easier to read.

Comment: Will Do, sorry.
Done.